# Naming database table fields (count vs counter)

Tags: naming-conventions

I have a database table with some **counters**: Favorites, Hits, Comments, etc.

What is the best name for this fields? Should I use the term '**FavoritesCounter**' or '**FavoritesCount**'?

Examples:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_example` (
  `IdExample` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '(PK)',
  ...
  `FavoritesCounter` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Number of times that example has been favorited.',
  ...
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_example` (
  `IdExample` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '(PK)',
  ...
  `FavoritesCount` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Number of times that example has been favorited.',
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the fields should have the noun contex. So "FavoritesCount" works well for database. The verb equivalent is "FavoritesCounter" and is used for denoting interactions, which is generally used in application code. The above echoes with your other fields such as Favorites, Hits and Comments.